# Parameterize the source or git repo name in AWS codebuild pipeline

Tags: github, cicd, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Is there a way to parameterize the git repo name and branch name in source stage of the AWS build pipeline. I have to run same pipeline against multiple repos and my existing setup is 1 pipeline for 1 repo, and I wanted to change it in a way I can use a single pipeline for multiple repos and passing repo name as a parameter.

One way is to update the repo name before triggering the pipeline, but want to know if there is a way to pass it dynamically or select for a drop down or a radio button ( as in Active choices extension of Jenkins).

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64422800/1273882